# Apache storm rollingFile problems

Tags: ubuntu, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper, nimbus

I set up apache storm cluster and as the tutorial said I run into three terminals the following:

```
storm nimbus
storm supervisor
storm ui
```

one in each terminal. So I got the following errors

> ....
>     ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in appenders.
>
> ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in appenders.
>
> ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in appenders.
>
> ERROR Unable to locate appender ACCESS for logger 
>   backtype.storm.security.auth.authorizer
>
> ERROR Unable to locate appender A1 for logger
>
> ERROR Unable to locate appender METRICS for logger backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer
>
> ....

and when I connected on my ip on the browser this comes up:
[image]

any thoughts?

Comment: which version are you using? Nimbus is most likely not running, hence the exception in UI. Paste the errors in nimbus.log here.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things you can check.

1. did you setup the storm.yaml file in conf folder? mine looks like this (i am using storm 10)..
   storm.zookeeper.servers:

   - ""
     nimbus.host: ""'
2. did you start the zookeeper? i started it like this:
   ./zkServer.sh start
   (i installed it in /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/)
3. did you start all these and nimbus and the supervisor and ui as root (or a user with enough rights)?